# How do I change the attributes of a dependencies?

Tags: reactjs

So I am trying to learn how to use the npm library, and I found this carousel. I implemented it into my project, but I am unsure about how to change the attributes. Here is the doc: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-carousel
and here is my current code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import "react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css";
import { Carousel } from 'react-responsive-carousel';
import Project1 from './Project1'
import Project2 from './Project2'


class Projects extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        showArrows: 'false',
        showIndicators: 'false'
      }
    }

    render() {
      const styles = {
        display: 'none'
      }
        return (
           <Carousel>
                 <div>
                    <Project1 />
                </div>
                <div>
                <img style = {styles}src="http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-640-480-1.jpg" />
                    <Project2 />
                </div>

            </Carousel>
        );
    }
};

export default Projects
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as you will do for normal components.
`<Carousel showArrows={false} showIndicators={false}>`

Refer [for demos.](http://react-responsive-carousel.js.org/)